# How to grant permissions to lock a table on Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm trying to lock a table in my python script (to avoid a serialization isolation error), using a Redshift DB table (table1).  I'm getting the following error, and I can't figure out what permissions to grant to allow table locking.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege) permission denied for relation table1
[SQL: begin; lock table1;]
```

The SQL code is in the 2nd line above - simply:

```
    begin; lock table1;
```

I've looked at the AWS documentation (like [Grant](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GRANT.html) and [Lock](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LOCK.html)) and also scoured Google and can't seem to find anything referencing what permissions Lock is under.  Any help appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that UPDATE, DELETE, or TRUNCATE permission will allow the user to perform an explicit LOCK on a table.  INSERT permission is not enough and this comes from Postgres and some corner cases that can be set up.